# Multiple underlines with multiple colors

Tags: color, highlighting

I would like to highlight the text that corresponds to many persons. I think underline is a good highlighting method. But I can put only one color for the underline.

```
\usepackage{soul,xcolor}
\setul{0.2ex}{0.2ex}
\newcommand\cul[2]{\setulcolor{#1}\ul{#2}}
\newcommand\rA[1]{\cul{red}{#1}}
\newcommand\rB[1]{\cul{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand\rC[1]{\cul{green}{#1}}
```

I need something like `\newcommand\rAB[1]{\cul{red,blue}{#1}}`
Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you need this but here is an attempt using `ulem`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rAB}[2]{\bgroup \UL@setULdepth
 \markoverwith{\lower\ULdepth\hbox
   {\kern-.03em\vbox{\color{#1}\hrule width.2em\kern1.2\p@\color{#2}\hrule}\kern-.03em}}%
 \ULon}
\makeatother
\setlength{\ULdepth}{1ex}

\begin{document}
  Some text \rAB{red}{blue}{some thing} Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]